# Number of group homomorphisms from a cyclic group to a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ Let $G = \langle x_0\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $H$ a finite group. Then the number of group homomorphisms $\varphi:G\to H$ is equal to the number of elements $h\in H$ such that $\text{order}(h)|n$.

Call $H_0:=\{h\in H: \text{order}(h)|n \}$.

$\textbf{What I have so far:}$ I propose to make a bijection

$$\Phi:\text{Hom}(G,H)\to H_0:\varphi\mapsto \Phi(\varphi)=\varphi(x_0).$$

This is well defined as for all $\varphi \in \text{Hom}(G,H):\text{order}(\varphi(x_0))|n$, we use the fact that the order of an element $x$ divides $s$ iff $x^s=e$. So then $\varphi(x_0)^n=\varphi(x_0^n)=e_H$, and then $\varphi(x_0)\in H_0$.

It is definitely an injection, since the image of a groupmorphism on a cyclic domain is determined by $\varphi(x_0)$. So, if two morphisms send $x_0$ to the same $h\in H_0$, they must be the same.

I am having trouble proving it is a surjection. Take $h\in H_0$. If there is a $\varphi \in\text{Hom}(G,H):\varphi(x_0)=h$, then all is well. But why should there be such a $\varphi$?

Comment: I just realised that the answer may be the following:

Any $\varphi:G\to H$ for which $\varphi(x_0)\in H$ defines a homomorphism. So for any $h\in H$ there is a $\varphi\in \text{Hom}(G,H)$ such that $\varphi(x_0)=h\in H_0$.

Comment: Yes. You can just define a homomorphism by specifying the image of the generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define one as you did before. You said that a homomorphism from a cyclic group is determined by the image of the generator. Now define $\varphi_h$ by sending your generator to the given element in $h \in H_0$.

Comment: Yes, I just realised this, and added it as a comment myself... Well, as it is an intersting problem, I guess other people will benefit from it anyway.

Comment: Sure and it is nice that you figured it out yourself.